# How to hide an embedded image from a Shopify shortcode?

Tags: wordpress, shopify

I am using the Shopify plugin which inserts Shopify products into Wordpress. I am trying to hide the image that gets brought in via the shortode. I've tried css and jquery but can't get it to be hidden.

So link for example: http://dev.whydidibother.com/airdecksltd_09_09_16/shop/6-board-pod/ - it is the image directly above the title and price.

Thanks

Comment: Is this possible? Sorry still a newbie

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following CSS:

```
.product-embed__image {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: hi, had tried that but it doesn't hide the image that is embedded from the Shopify shortcode